# JQL query for Fetch all the jira tickets with status "Pending Merge" and order them by ascending order of status update to this

Tags: jira, jql

How to create a JQL query for fetching all the jira tickets with status "Pending Merge" and the first ticket which I get should be the first ticket whose status was changed to "Pending Merge"

what is the jql for that?

JQL--->"status=Pending Merge order by ASC".This query fetches all the tickets with Pending merge status and sorts them by ascending order of Jira-ID.But I want the ticket whose status was changed to Pending merge first to be in the first and so on .

What should the query be for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general JQL for that.

Alternative 1:
If the workflow sets the resolution during the transition to "Pending Merge" then you can order by resolution date.
`status = "Pending Merge" order by resolved ASC`

Alternative 2:
This will order by last updated date. The updated date does also change on other events.
`status = "Pending Merge" order by updated ASC`

Alternative 3:
You need to use Automation rules or third party Marketplace Apps to save a timestamp in a a customfield during the transition to "Pending Merge".